# How to write unit test using jest for directive in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest, angular14

I am using the jest to cover the unit test in my angular project and I am new to unit test using jest.

Below is my code for DragDropDirective:

```
    @HostListener('dragenter',['$event'])
    @HostListener('dragover',['$event'])
    public handleDragOver(event:DragEvent):void{
       if(!this.enabled){
            return;
       }
       event.dataTransfer?.dropEffect=='move';
       this.stopAndPreventDefault(event);
       this._dragInProgress=true;
    }
    


    @HostListener('dragleave',['$event'])
    @HostListener('dragend',['$event'])
    public handleDragEnd(event:DragEvent):void{
      if(!this.enabled){
         return;
      }
      this.stopAndPreventDefault(event);
      event.dataTransfer?.effectAllowed=='copy';
      this._dragInProgress=false;
    }

    stopAndPreventDefault(e:UIEvent):void{
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to write unit tests for **DragDropDirective** using `Jest`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { DragDropDirective } from "./drag-drop.directive";

@Component({
  template: `<div appDragDrop></div>`,
})
class TestComponent {}

describe("DragDropDirective", () => {
  let fixture: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DragDropDirective, TestComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should set _dragInProgress to true on drag enter or drag over", () => {
    const div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("div");
    const event = new DragEvent("dragover");
    const directive = div.directive;
    directive.enabled = true;
    directive.handleDragOver(event);
    expect(directive._dragInProgress).toBe(true);
  });

  it("should set _dragInProgress to false on drag leave or drag end", () => {
    const div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("div");
    const event = new DragEvent("dragleave");
    const directive = div.directive;
    directive.enabled = true;
    directive.handleDragEnd(event);
    expect(directive._dragInProgress).toBe(false);
  });

  it("should not set _dragInProgress if disabled", () => {
    const div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("div");
    const event = new DragEvent("dragover");
    const directive = div.directive;
    directive.enabled = false;
    directive.handleDragOver(event);
    expect(directive._dragInProgress).toBe(false);
  });

  it("should call stopAndPreventDefault on drag enter, drag over, drag leave, and drag end", () => {
    const div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("div");
    const spy = spyOn(div.directive, "stopAndPreventDefault");
    const event1 = new DragEvent("dragover");
    const event2 = new DragEvent("dragleave");
    const directive = div.directive;
    directive.enabled = true;
    directive.handleDragOver(event1);
    directive.handleDragEnd(event2);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

The first two tests check that `_dragInProgress` is set correctly when the `handleDragOver` and `handleDragEnd` methods are called with a `DragEvent`.

The third test checks that `_dragInProgress` is not set if the directive is disabled.

The fourth test checks that `stopAndPreventDefault` is called when the `handleDragOver`, `handleDragEnd`, `handleDragEnter`, and `handleDragLeave` methods are called.

Comment: Here I am getting the errors (1).ReferenceError: DragEvent is not defined " (2).ReferenceError: spyOn is not defined "

Comment: Can you help me to cover this portion  event.dataTransfer?.effectAllowed=='copy';